# Picker in Scrollist in reactnative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

"Hi.. I am new to React native.  I can't code for picker in scroll list as its showing this.state undefined..
I want picker in  scroll list . Below is my code."

`

```
    'use strict';
      import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
      import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      ImageBackground,
      ScrollView,
      Dimensions,
      TouchableOpacity,Picker
       } from 'react-native';
       import ParallaxScrollView from 'react-native-parallax-scroll-view';
      let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

         /////////////////////////////scrollist containin picker/////////////////
       const ScrollList = (props) => {
        return (



          <View
          style={{alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space- 


           between',padding:10,backgroundColor:'#fff',
          borderBottomColor:'#efefef',borderBottomWidth:1}}>
          <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>

 <View style = {styles.container}>


         <Picker
         style={{width:'12%'}}
         selectedValue={this.state.PickerValue}
         onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)  => 
                 this.setState({PickerValue:itemValue})}
                 >
                <PickerItem label ="ffff"    value="dsfsf"/>
                 </Picker>
                 </View>


              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>


              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Japan</Text>
          </View>


          <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>


              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> ICICI</Text>


              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Indian</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Indian</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Indian</Text>



              </View>

             <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
               <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Carrot</Text>




              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Bean</Text>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Bean</Text>


              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> Bean</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> 934</Text>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> 000</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> 000</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> 000</Text>

          </View>

          <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> 93,943.44</Text>

              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> iu</Text>
              <Text style={{marginTop:5}}> iu</Text>


             </View>




             </View>



                  )
                    }
```

///////////////////////title  containing titles//////////////////
                      const TitleContent = (props) => {
                      return (
                       
                           
                             Pending Expenses
                          2020
                           June

```
                          <View style={{flex:1}}>

                      <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5 
                      ,textAlign:'center',color:'#000',fontWeight:"bold"}}>Location</Text>

                     </View>
                     <View style={{flex:1}}>

                      <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5 
                     ,textAlign:'center',color:'#000',fontWeight:"bold"}}>Bank</Text>

                       </View>
                       <View style={{flex:1}}>

                        <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5 
                      ,textAlign:'center',color:'#000',fontWeight:"bold"}}>Grocery</Text>

                       </View>
                      <View style={{flex:1}}>

                      <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5 
                      ,textAlign:'center',color:'#000',fontWeight:"bold"}}>Amt</Text>

                        </View>


                       <View style={{flex:1}}>

                      <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5 
                  ,textAlign:'center',color:'#000',fontWeight:"bold"}}>Camera</Text>

                 </View>




                   </View>
                </View>
               )
                 }



           export default class App extends PureComponent {




static propTypes = {};
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {PickerValue:''};



    }







componentDidMount() {
}
componentWillUnmount() {
}
```

//////////////describing view //////////

```
render() {
return (




  <View style={styles.container}>

    <TitleContent/>
      <ScrollView
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          contentBackgroundColor="'rgba(0,0,0,.4)'"
          headerBackgroundColor="#333"
          stickyHeaderHeight={40}
          parallaxHeaderHeight={250}
          backgroundSpeed={10}



          renderStickyHeader={() => (
              <View key="sticky-header" style={styles.stickySection}>
                  <Text style={styles.stickySectionText}>Details</Text>
              </View>
              )
          }

          renderFixedHeader ={ () => (
              <View key="fixed-header" style={styles.fixedSection}>

                  <TouchableOpacity style={{}} onPress={() => {}}>
                         <Text style={{color:'#fff',marginRight:10}}>ho</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  )
          }

      >


           <View style={styles.container}>


      </View>
          <View style={{marginTop:10}}>

              <ScrollList />
          </View>
      </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

`

Comment: Can you be more specific about whihc part of your code is trying to use this.state, but is getting an error?

Comment: onst ScrollList = (props) => {
  return (
   
      <View
          style={{alignItems:'flex-end',flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between',padding:10,backgroundColor:'#fff',borderBottomColor:'#efefef',borderBottomWidth:1}}>
          <View style = {styles.container}>
             

             <Picker
             style={{width:'12%'}}
             selectedValue={this.state.PickerValue}
             onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex)  => this.setState({PickerValue:itemValue})}
             >
<PickerItem label ="ffff"    value="dsfsf"/>
</Picker>
</View>

Comment: I am getting this error "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.state reactnative"

Comment: Kindly edit your post to include all the information. Do not use comments for this.

Comment: okay I edited my post

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @ShrujanaN, I'm guessing the folks who answer angular questions need a little more information about what is happening than a large block of code and a partial error message. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask